SQL how to sort by three column but in tree like structure
Database is mariadb. So this is my table and i want to sort it by 'id' descending but with the children always below the parent.
+----+-----------+--------------+--------+----------+
| id | firstName | favoriteFood | status | parentID |
+----+-----------+--------------+--------+----------+
| 1  |   Andy    |    pizza     | child  |    5     |
| 2  |   Alice   |    burger    | child  |    5     |
| 3  |    Bob    |    fries     | orphan |   null   |
| 4  |  Barney   |    salad     | parent |   null   |
| 5  |  Christ   |    steak     | parent |   null   |
| 6  |  Daniel   |    pizza     | child  |    8     |
| 7  |   Mike    |    fries     | child  |    5     |
| 8  |  Richard  |   oatmeal    | parent |   null   |
| 9  |  Wilson   |    steak     | child  |    8     |
| 10 |   Dicky   |  watermelon  | orphan |   null   |
| 11 |   Freya   |    potato    | orphan |   null   |
| 12 |   Ryan    |    oyster    | parent |   null   |
| 13 |   Alex    |    bread     | orphan |   null   |
| 14 |   Sarah   |   brocoli    | child  |    12    |
| 15 |   Dane    |    toast     | child  |    8     |
+----+-----------+--------------+--------+----------+

I tried with this but it doesnt give my expected result
SELECT * from table ORDER BY id DESC, FIELD(status,'parent','child'), parentID

and this my expected result if its possible:
+----+-----------+--------------+--------+----------+
| id | firstName | favoriteFood | status | parentID |
+----+-----------+--------------+--------+----------+
| 13 |   Alex    |    bread     | orphan |   null   |
| 12 |   Ryan    |    oyster    | parent |   null   |
| 14 |   Sarah   |   brocoli    | child  |    12    |
| 11 |   Freya   |    potato    | orphan |   null   |
| 10 |   Dicky   |  watermelon  | orphan |   null   |
| 8  |  Richard  |   oatmeal    | parent |   null   |
| 15 |   Dane    |    toast     | child  |    8     |
| 9  |  Wilson   |    steak     | child  |    8     |
| 6  |  Daniel   |    pizza     | child  |    8     |
| 5  |  Christ   |    steak     | parent |   null   |
| 7  |   Mike    |    fries     | child  |    5     |
| 2  |   Alice   |    burger    | child  |    5     |
| 1  |   Andy    |    pizza     | child  |    5     |
| 4  |  Barney   |    salad     | parent |   null   |
| 3  |    Bob    |    fries     | orphan |   null   |
+----+-----------+--------------+--------+----------+


Your expected result makes no sense. I can't see any column that is sorted in any way. Sorting by id DESC first will put 15 at the top and 1 at the bottom. What are you sorting by to get the result you show?

Given that you don't seem to have more than one level of parent/child, you don't need recursion for this.  Simply sort children with their parent, but with the parent first:
select MyTbl.*
from MyTbl
order by
  coalesce(parentID,id) desc,
  parentID is not null,
  id desc

fiddle
